# Почему BLOB-данные из одной таблицы MySql не передаются в другую?

Tags: mysql, blob

Нужно скопировать данные BLOB из одной таблицы в другую, но они почему-то не переносятся. Они приходят, но почему-то не записываются.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    $sql_bx="insert into usr_files (FILENAME, FBID, TYPE, FILE) values(
        '".$row['FILENAME']."',
        '".$row['FBID']."',
        '".$row['TYPE']."',
        '".$row['FILE']."');";
    mysqli_query($db_bx_link, $sql_bx);
    echo mysqli_error($db_bx_link);
    break;
}
```

В $row['FILE'] находятся эти данные.

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_bx_link, "INSERT INTO usr_files VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
    $code = $row['FILENAME'];
    $language = $row['FBID'];
    $official = $row['TYPE'];
    $percent = $row['FILE'];
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    printf("%d строк вставлено.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
    break;
}
```

Ответ: 0 строк вставлено

Comment: потому что вы подставляете значения переменных непосредственно в запрос. Вы пишите `values( 'X' )` и если этот X равен например `xx 'abc' xx` то итоговая строка содержит лишние кавычки. _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения прямо в запрос, _всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку значений https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: А вообще перенос данных из одной таблицы в другую надо производить не на php, а одним sql-запросом insert ... select ...

Comment: Переписал по мануалу, результата все-равно нет. Или что-то неправильно сделал?

Comment: "А вообще перенос данных из одной таблицы в другую надо производить не на php, а одним sql-запросом" дело в том, что эту процедуру нужно производить по крону раз в сутки.

Comment: Запрос можно выполнить из php, так же по крону, раз в сутки. Только никаких циклов не понадобится. Кроме того в mysql есть свой планировщик задач https://habr.com/ru/post/123391/ и он отлично справится с задачей вообще без крона и php

Comment: по поводу почему сейчас вставлено 0 строк не знаю, текущий код выглядит корректно. попробуйте выводить ошибки, если их не выводите другими средствами (глобально не включены)

Comment: Вот такая ошибка "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: Значит в таблице более 4х колонок. Перечислите явно колонки, как вы делали в первый раз

Comment: А вообще prepare хорош тем, что сам prepare и bind_param достаточно выполнить один раз, перед циклом. А в цикле только заполнение привязанных переменных и вызов execute

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!

Comment: Не, строка добавилось, но в поле FILE - пустота